# react rc-table fixed column creating duplicates

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using [rc-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-table) component in my react application. rc-table has a feature for making columns fixed (http://react-component.github.io/table/examples/fixedColumns.html). In my case the fixed columns are duplicated and shown as a new table under the actual table.

I've tried quite a few things but nothing worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're including  rc-table css?

```
import 'rc-table/assets/index.css';
```